# How to make the output of this classic pyramids into list in Python

Tags: python, list

I want the output for this code to be a list how should I do it I'm very new to python so sorry if this look silly

```
s = "Hello, World!"
for i in range(len(s)+ 1): 
    a = print(s[:i])
print(a)
```

The output would be:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello,
Hello, 
Hello, W
Hello, Wo
Hello, Wor
Hello, Worl
Hello, World
Hello, World!
```

How can I output it like:

```
[       "H",
        "He",
        "Hel",
        "Hell",
        "Hello",
        "Hello,",
        "Hello, ",
        "Hello, W",
        "Hello, Wo",
        "Hello, Wor",
        "Hello, Worl",
        "Hello, World",
        "Hello, World!",
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) built-in function does:

```
from itertools import accumulate

result = list(accumulate('Hello, World!'))
```

If you prefer something maybe easier to understand:

```
s = 'Hello, World!'
result = []
for i in range(len(s) + 1):
    result.append(s[:i])
```

The previous approach can also be written using a list comprehension:

```
s = 'Hello, World!'
result = [s[:i] for i in range(len(s) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty list (let's call it `string_list`)at the beginning of your code and append each substring to that list with `string_list.append(s)` instead of printing the substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Hello, World!"
my_list = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        my_list.append(s[:i+1])
my_list
```

Output:

```
['H',
 'He',
 'Hel',
 'Hell',
 'Hello',
 'Hello,',
 'Hello, ',
 'Hello, W',
 'Hello, Wo',
 'Hello, Wor',
 'Hello, Worl',
 'Hello, World',
 'Hello, World!']
```

The pythonic way is a list comprehension:

```
s = "Hello, World!"
[s[:i+1] for i in range(len(s))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
print("[")
[print('"' + s[:i] + '"') for i in range(len(s)+ 1)]
print("]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Hello, World!"
qqq = []
for i in range(len(s)+ 1):
    a = print(s[:i])
    qqq.append(s[:i])
    
print(a)
print(qqq)
```